# Properly implementing a Delegate & Protocol

Tags: iphone, cocoa, cocoa-touch, delegates, protocols

I created this test case as a simple example of my problem.

- The AppDelegate initializes the TestViewController and adds it to the window
- The TestViewController initializes the TestView and makes it the view
- The TestView initializes the TestSubView and adds it as a subview

My goal is to allow TestSubView, through a delegate, access to TestViewController's methods & variables. In this example TestSubView accesses the methods through either a touchesBegan or touchesMoved.

Please Help. Thank you.

EDIT: Still doesn't work, though no more errors. What I did: Moved the protocol definition to a separate file and imported it, retain to assign, and removed the @protocol TestDelegate declaration in the beginning of the header.

I think my problem is that I don't assign the delegate in the TestViewController.m, if that's the problem how would I do that?

TestViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface TestViewController : UIViewController <TestDelegate> {

    int number;
}

-(void)assignNumber:(int)value;
-(void)displayNumber;

@property int number;

@end
```

Moved to protocol.h and imported where needed

```
@protocol TestDelegate

-(void)assignNumber:(int)value;
-(void)displayNumber;

@end
```

TestViewController.m

```
#import "TestViewController.h"
#import "TestView.h"

@implementation TestViewController

@synthesize number;

- (void)loadView {
    TestView *myView = [[TestView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,480)];
    self.view = myView;
    [myView release];
}

-(void)assignNumber:(int)value {
    NSLog(@"Number Assigned");
    number = value;
}

-(void)displayNumber {
    NSLog(@"%i",number);
}
```

TestSubView.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "TestViewController.h"


@interface TestSubView : UIView {

    id<TestDelegate> delegate;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) id<TestDelegate> delegate;

@end
```

TestSubView.m

```
#import "TestSubView.h"
#import "TestViewController.h"

@implementation TestSubView

@synthesize delegate;

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    if ((self = [super initWithFrame:frame])) {
        // Initialization code
        [self setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
        [self setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
    }
    return self;
}


- (void)dealloc {
    [super dealloc];
}

- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    [self.delegate assignNumber:5];
}

- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    [self.delegate displayNumber];  
}
```

Comment: When you declare methods in a protocol, you don't need to declare those methods again in a class that conforms to the protocol. (Indeed, you shouldn't, since this leads to mismatch errors later on if you change one but not the other.) Also, why `assignNumber:`? I suggest just declaring the property in the protocol.

Comment: Can you add your TestView class? Thats the glue thats missing here and could be where your problem is.

Comment: is TestSubView meant to be TestView?

Answer (score 0):

First and foremost, you're declaring a protocol and then assigning the same object as implementing that protocol. What you're probably looking for is to declare the TestDelegate protocol on your TestSubView instead. Additionally when setting up a property for a delegate, be sure to use the 'assign' keyword as opposed to 'retain'.

Finally all of this can be greatly simplified by using UIGestureRecognizer. You can set it up in your controller and add it to your testSubView. This way, when the view recognizes that the corresponding gesture occurred within it's bounds, a message will be sent to your controller allowing you to do what you need to do like assigning or displaying a number.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I still haven't got it to work but got rid of all the errors. Updated above. I'll take a look at the GestureRecognizer.

Answer (score 0):

You're referring to `TestView` when your class is called `TestSubView`, unless you have 2 classes defined.

`TestView *myView = [[TestView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,480)];`

You're correct that you're not assigning the delegate yet.
You would do that on the next line:

`myView.delegate = self;`

To end up with this:

```
- (void)loadView {
    TestSubView *myView = [[TestSubView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,480)];
    myView.delegate = self; // Set Delegate Here
    self.view = myView;
    [myView release];
}
```